# Function passed down from parent to child works fine if called from any pressable but goes haywire if called from a React Native modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a parent component called `Players` which iterates over an array and renders a `Player` component for each player in the array. It also passes down a `deletePlayer()` function that just logs the player for now.

Every instance of `Player.tsx` renders the name of the player, and if you click the name, it should set `showDeleteDialog` to `true` which would bring up the delete dialog

After that, if the user clicks the first button, it should execute the `deletePlayer()` function with the specific player.

Now here is the problem - right now my code always console.logs the same player no matter which name I click BUT this only happens if I execute the `deletePlayer()` function from the modal. If I replace:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => setShowDeleteDialog(true)}><Text>{player.name}</Text></Pressable>
```

With:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => deletePlayer(player)}><Text>{player.name}</Text></Pressable>
```

It works as intended. This means that me calling `deletePlayer()` from the React Native modal somehow affects how `deletePlayer()` functions.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Players.tsx

```
const Players: = () => {
    const [showDeleteDialog, setShowDeleteDialog] = useState(false)

    const deletePlayer = (player) => {
        console.log(player)
    }

    return (
        <View>
            {players.map((player) => (
                <Player
                    player={player}
                    key={player.id}
                    deletePlayer={deletePlayer}
                    showDeleteDialog={showDeleteDialog}
                    setShowDeleteDialog={setShowDeleteDialog}
                />
            ))}
        </View>
    );
};
```

I also have a `deletePlayer()` function and a `showDeleteDialog` boolean which I pass down as well.

In `Player.tsx`, I have the following:

```
const Player: = ({
    player,
    deletePlayer,
    showDeleteDialog,
    setShowDeleteDialog
}) => {

    return (
        <>
            <Pressable onPress={() => setShowDeleteDialog(true)}><Text>{player.name}</Text></Pressable>
            {showDelete && (
                <Modal animationType="fade" transparent onRequestClose={onDismiss} {...rest}>
                    <InnerContainer innerWidth={innerWidth!}>
                            <Text>Delete?</Text>
                            <View>
                                <Button
                                    title="Yes"
                                    onPress={() => deletePlayer(player}
                                />
                                <Button
                                    title="No"
                                    onPress={() => setShowDeleteDialog(false)}
                                />
                            </View>
                    </InnerContainer>
                </Modal>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

I've applied my current code and tried everything I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing the same function to every component which results in the same player value, instead of doing that create this function for every player component.
Do something like this :

```
{players.map((player) => {
    const [showDeleteDialog, setShowDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
    const deletePlayer = () => {
       console.log(player);
    }
    return (
        <Player
            key={player.id}
            player={player}
            deletePlayer={deletePlayer}
            showDeleteDialog={showDeleteDialog}
            setShowDeleteDialog={setShowDeleteDialog}
        />
    )
})}
```